Which Python 2.7.x version is compatible with both Cassandra 3.11 and 4.1?
I'm upgrading Cassandra from 3.11 to 4.1. One of the requirements is the latest python 2.7 updates. I want to upgrade Cassandra with no downtime, so I need to know which python 2.7 update is compatible with both Cassandra 3.11 and Cassandra 4.1. Datastax doc on upgrading apache cassandra asked for the latest python 2.7, but it doesn't explicitly say which version and whether that python version is compatible with both versions of cassandra 3.11 and 4.1
I tried python 2.7.5 which work for cqlsh of Cassandra 3.11, but it does not work for cqlsh of Cassandra 4.1.

Python 2 support was officially removed as of CASSANDRA-17242, which was merged into the alpha release of Cassandra 4.1. Therefore, the version of cqlsh bundled with Cassandra 4.1 can only be run on Python 3.x.

Python is not needed for Cassandra but for the client cqlsh client which is very useful for local administration.
I have a cluster where for testing I have installed both Cassandra 3.11 and 4.11 and my solution is to install both python versions, python2 for 3.11, and python3 for 4 and above. Some OS like Ubuntu allow you to install them both directly from the package manager and cqlsh takes the correct python version by itself.

The docs do not explicitly state a "compatible" version other than "the latest version" because Python 2.7 is very old and has reached the end of its life, officially sunset on January 2020.
It is pointless to even bother testing Python 2.7.5 given it's over 10 years old (released in 2013). Even Python 2.7.18 which is the last and latest version was released all the way back to 2020.
In any case, Python is not required to run Cassandra as a server. It is only needed by certain clients, specifically cqlsh. Being a client, there is no requirement to have Python-compatibility with Cassandra 3.11 and 4.1 for cqlsh since it is not part of the Cassandra server.
If Python versions is such an issue in your environment, consider using a Python virtual environment to run cqlsh. Cheers!
